# Действия над числами в пятеричной системе счисления

Tags: системы-счисления

Некоторое устройство позволяет хранить четырёхразрядные числа в семеричной системе счисления. Отрицательные числа представляются в дополнительном коде, то есть, например, число -1 представляется в этом устройстве как 6666 (в семиричной системе счисления).

Представьте в этом устройстве результат выполнения операции:

```
242 (в пятиричной) - 244 (в пятиричной) = Х (в пятиричной).
```

Мои вопросы:

1. Что означает "УСТРОЙСТВО ПОЗВОЛЯЕТ ХРАНИТЬ"?
2. Что такое вообще "n-РАЗРЯДНЫЕ ЧИСЛА"?
3. Как решить данную задачу?
4. Что такое "дополнительный код"?
5. Какую литературу вы предлагаете прочесть, чтобы решать задачи такого рода?

Честно говоря, я "0" по информатике, что советуете, чтобы хорошо и фундаментально учить её?

Answer (score 1):

-1. Не заморачивайтесь.

Если все же надо, "позволяет" - то это и означает. Например, "позволяет хранить четырёхразрядные числа в семеричной системе счисления" означает, что некоторое устройство способно хранить 4 цифры в одном числе, при этом каждая цифра меньше 7.

-2-3,5. Советую прочитать [эту статью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). Для решения задач такого рода этого хватит.

-4. Советую прочитать [эту статью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)).

P.S.: "что советуете, чтобы хорошо и фундаментально учить её?" Информатика - [обширная наука](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0), здесь и ПО (использование и написание), алгоритмы, железо и т.д.

Чтобы изучить ее, читайте статьи по теме, хоть как-то связанной с информатикой (про антивирусы, почту, интернет, программы, алгоритмы/языки, стандарты и т.д.). Начинать лучше с основ. Когда будете свободно понимать, о чем говорится в книгах/статьях, можно начинать знакомиться уже со специализированной литературой.

Но в этом случае ваши знания все равно в общем будут поверхностными. Что-то вы будете знать больше остальных, но в общем - гораздо меньше. Поэтому лучше будет выбрать направление, которое вам нравится больше, и читать больше про него. Т.к. все взаимосвязанно, то и остальные направления со временем подтянутся.

Хотя на первых порах почитать обо всем (без углубления) лишним не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ: 6665.

Делается обычное вычитание в столбик с заёмом, но с такими отличиями:

- в семиричной системе мы занимаем по 7, а не по 10
- четырёхразрядное устройство понимает не более таких 4 цифр
- допкод состоит в том, что при выходе за пределы разрядной сетки (т.е. при выходе на пятый разряд) заём теряется, "нет разряда - нет проблемы".